Composing stream homomorphisms "apply f" based on dynamical systems (A, f)
I'm trying to do Exercise 99 of Rutten's The method of coalgebra: exercises in coinduction. It says

For all functions $f: A \to A$ and $g: A \to A$, prove that $$\text{apply}_g \circ \text{apply}_f = \text{apply}_{g\circ f}$$ by coinduction.

This amounts to finding a bisimulation relation containing the pair $(\text{apply}_g \circ \text{apply}_f, \text{apply}_{g\circ f})$ for all $f,g: A \rightrightarrows A$. This chapter has been about streams, so taking the relation $$R=\{(\text{apply}_g \circ \text{apply}_f, \text{apply}_{g\circ f}) \hspace{1mm}|\hspace{1mm} f,g: A \rightrightarrows A \},$$ if

$(\text{apply}_g \circ \text{apply}_f)(0)=(\text{apply}_{g\circ f})(0)$
$((\text{apply}_f \circ \text{apply}_f)',(\text{apply}_{g\circ f})')\in R$

then $R$ is a stream bisimulation, making the equation we want to prove true.
However, they haven't defined apply$_f$ anywhere yet and I'm having trouble seeing how to interpret it as a stream homomorphism, so I don't know what the first element or derivative of the image of apply$_f$ would look like. I assume apply$_f$ has to commute with a stream system based on $f$, so maybe one where states are elements of $A$ and which outputs $a$ and transitions to f(a), so that apply$_f$ maps every element $a\in A$ to the stream $(a, f(a), f(f(a)), \dots)$. In that case, apply$_f$ is a stream homomorphism from $(A, \langle id, f \rangle)$ to the final stream $(A^\omega, \langle i_{st}, d_{st} \rangle)$ where $i_{st}(\sigma)=\sigma(0)$ and $d_{st}(\sigma)=\sigma'$ for all streams $\sigma\in A^\omega$. Then the relation I want to show is a bisimulation is $$R=\{((\text{apply}_g \circ \text{apply}_f)(a), (\text{apply}_{g\circ f})(a)) \hspace{1mm}|\hspace{1mm} \forall f,g: A \rightrightarrows A, \forall a \in A \}.$$
And the way I think I'll do that is to show something like

$(\text{apply}_g\circ\text{apply}_f)(a)(0)=\text{apply}_{g\circ f}(a)(0),$
$(\text{apply}_g\circ\text{apply}_f)(a)'=(\text{apply}_g\circ\text{apply}_f)(g\circ f(a))$
$(\text{apply}_{g\circ f})(a)'=(\text{apply}_{g\circ f})(g \circ f(a))$

since these last two equalities would imply $((\text{apply}_g \circ \text{apply}_f)(a)',(\text{apply}_{g\circ f})(a)')\in R$. But the way I've defined things, $\text{apply}_f,\text{apply}_g: A \rightrightarrows A^\omega$ are not composable, so I'm still unable to interpret some of these equations.
In fact, I don't see how apply$_f$ and apply$_g$ could possibly be composable if they are homomorphisms to the final object, which I thought they had to be to use coinduction (unless they're id$_{A^\omega}$, which I seriously doubt).
I feel like I'm complicating things unnecessarily. Where am I going wrong, and how do I interpret the functions and operations in this problem?

They haven't defined $\mathsf{apply}$ anywhere, so the exercise is bogus, but my guess is that given $f : A \to B$, $\mathsf{apply}_f : A^\omega \to B^\omega$ is the obvious function that applies $f$ to every element of a stream. It's unclear why the exercise restricts to the case $B = A$, but I suggest doing it in full generality.

(That is, $f : A \to B$, $g : B \to C$. If you additionally prove that $\mathsf{apply}_\mathrm{id} = \mathrm{id}$, then you'll have proved that $-^\omega$ is a functor.)
